# Select child of earlier clicked item in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have clicked on a div. In this div is an image:

```
<div class="grid_2 shareContent" id="facebook_45">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="facebook"  
             src="http://roepingen.kk/skins/admin/default/images/social/facebook.png"
             alt="Facebook not shared" width="32px" height="32px" />
    </a>
</div>
```

How can I change the image in the div?
I have the clicked item saved in the variable 'clicked'.
If possible I'd like to delete the link around the image also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).find("img")
           .attr("src", "newImage.jpg");
           .unwrap("a");
});
```

Comment: Can't you do `$(this).find("img").attr("src", "newImage.jpg").unwrap("a");`?

Comment: @simshaun - You are not mistaken at all. It can be done like that. I will edit, good point btw :)